# Ionic compile error: cannot find symbol import android.webkit.ClientCertRequest;

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools

Cant compile my app on ubuntu when I try `ionic build android`

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

My Project.Properties

```
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
```

My error:

```
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava/home/fernando/Dropbox/Code/Kelps/KelpsApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaClientCertRequest.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
import android.webkit.ClientCertRequest;

symbol:   class ClientCertRequest
  location: package android.webkit
/home/fernando/Dropbox/Code/Kelps/KelpsApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaClientCertRequest.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    private final ClientCertRequest request;

symbol:   class ClientCertRequest
  location: class CordovaClientCertRequest
/home/fernando/Dropbox/Code/Kelps/KelpsApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaClientCertRequest.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
    public CordovaClientCertRequest(ClientCertRequest request) {
                                    ^
  symbol:   class ClientCertRequest
  location: class CordovaClientCertRequest
/home/fernando/Dropbox/Code/Kelps/KelpsApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebViewClient.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
import android.webkit.ClientCertRequest;
```

[...]

```
symbol:   variable LOLLIPOP
  location: class VERSION_CODES
/home/fernando/Dropbox/Code/Kelps/KelpsApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemCookieManager.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
            cookieManager.flush();
                         ^
  symbol:   method flush()
  location: variable cookieManager of type CookieManager
/home/fernando/Dropbox/Code/Kelps/KelpsApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebChromeClient.java:257: error: cannot find symbol
                    Uri[] result = WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent);
                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable FileChooserParams
  location: class WebChromeClient
/home/fernando/Dropbox/Code/Kelps/KelpsApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebChromeClient.java:250: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
14 errors
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Install ionic enviroment with https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/

Already tried to remove platform and add platform again.

Someone got this error before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`android.webkit.ClientCertRequest`, this class requires API level 21 or higher.
`android:targetSdkVersion` and `target` should be 21 or higher.
One way is to install API 21 or higher. Another way is to add the older android platform by running `ionic platforms add android@3.6.4`.
Now the command `ionic build android` will work.

Comment: the version of platform must be lower than 3.6.4